# issue with html <pre> tag

Tags: html, css

i have a requirement like.

key :this is the value
type : this is the type value

Iam using `<pre>` tag ,after using it is displaying something like

```
key1 :this is the value
          type1 : this is the type value

          key2 :this is the value
          type2 : this is the type value

key2 :this is the value
          type2 : this is the type value
```

my reuirement is to next key,type should start from the beginning

```
key1 :this is the value
type1 : this is the type value

key2 :this is the value
type2 : this is the type value
```

Comment: And so what is the question ?

Comment: mu queestion is like,pre tag contains any attributes to align text from begining orany alternative tags to pre tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this css class.

**CSS:**

```
pre { white-space:pre-line;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <pre>key1 :this is the value
        type1 : this is the type value

        key2 :this is the value
        type2 : this is the type value

        key2 :this is the value
        type2 : this is the type value</pre>
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
key1 :this is the value
type1 : this is the type value

key2 :this is the value
type2 : this is the type value

key2 :this is the value
type2 : this is the type value
```

Comment: Why use pre tag then, you can directly add css to div and make it work  div { white-space:pre-line; font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-size:80%  }

Comment: That was created just for reference, I have targeted directly <pre> only in css. We can remove extra DIV.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that you are preformatting your text, then preformat your text.

Don't add whitespace to the start of the subsequent lines to satisfy the indentation of your source code. Only add whitespace if you want it.

So change:

```
<div>
    <pre>foo
    bar
    baz
    </pre>
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
    <pre>foo
bar
baz
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: i am not adding any space    <pre style="white-space: normal;"><s:property value="%{fileContent}" /></pre>.this is my code

Comment: Why on earth would you use `white-space: normal` on a `<pre>` element?! (And don't show JSP, show the HTML it generates).

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided your HTML code.It works fine if you format the html content properly

```
<pre>
key1 :this is the value
type1 : this is the type value

key2 :this is the value
type2 : this is the type value

key2 :this is the value
type2 : this is the type value

</pre>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UUgpk/

Comment: <pre style="white-space: normal;"><s:property value="%{fileContent}" /> </pre>..this is my code

Comment: Does the fileContent return properly formatted text(Like the one shown in my answer) ?

Comment: Also why use white-space: normal; ??. The pre tag is meant to include all the whitespace and newlines as present in the content.